# Import compressed SQL dump into Postgresql with python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have to import a compressed sql dump into a PostgreSQL database.
The dump gets created by:

```
pg_dump -F c
```

So I get a compressed file, which I can't just parse line by line and then use psycopg2 to upload it into my database.

The compressed dumps I'm dealing with are quite big (up to 10GB). What would be an efficient way to do import them?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't re-import using the command line?  Doing it through Python is going to be inefficient.

Comment: If you have to "control" it via Python, you can always execute the necessary command line command from within Python.

Comment: Why not just use postgres's own tools, such as pg_restore?

Comment: Do you know what compression algorithm it uses?

Comment: @Keith: Its own, as its says in the man. File is 'src/bin/pg_dump/pg_backup_archiver.c' in the source tree. It uses zlib but it has its own structure. Its not just zipped. Best bet would probably be interfacing with it in C  and using the pg headers if you really have to do it this way.

Comment: The script running this, is called by a webserver. Until now I thought, since I can't provide a password through ~/.pgpass there is no other way on doing this. But I just discovered that there is PGPASSWORD as an environment variable. I should be able to use that.

Comment: import it locally into your own postgres server and export it again as csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically can't do that unless you reimplement `pg_restore` in your Python project.  Consider instead calling `pg_restore` from your Python program.